# Saving Image to file from imagePickerController - unable to load image

Tags: ios, xcode, uiimagepickercontroller, nsdata

I'm not quite sure whats going wrong here, I'd really appreciate some help as I'm very stuck.
This is my `imagePickerController`

```
-(void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:[NSNumber numberWithLong:customphoto1] forKey:@"customphoto1count"];
        UIImage *button1Image = [info objectForKey:@"UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage"];


    pngData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(button1Image);
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsPath = [paths objectAtIndex:0]; //Get the docs directory
    NSString *filePath = [documentsPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Button1image.png"]; //Add the file name
    [pngData writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES]; //Write the file
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];
    pngData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:filePath];
    UIImage *imageLoaded = [UIImage imageWithData:pngData];
    [_button1 setImage:imageLoaded forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    self.button1.clipsToBounds = YES;
    self.button1.layer.cornerRadius = (self.button1.frame.size.width / 16);//half of the width
    self.button1.layer.borderColor=[UIColor blackColor].CGColor;
    self.button1.layer.borderWidth=1.0f;
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];
}
```

The above saves the image (as far as I believe) since `_button1` is reading from `imageLoaded`

When the app closes and is reopened, this is the what calls the button to be displayed, and should load the picture from my NSData:

```
-(void)customButton1{
    if (customphoto1 == 1) {
        NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
        NSString *documentsPath = [paths objectAtIndex:0]; //Get the docs directory
        NSString *filePath = [documentsPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Button1image.png"]; //Add the file name
        [pngData writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES];
        pngData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:filePath];
        UIImage *imageLoaded1 = [UIImage imageWithData:pngData];
        NSLog(@"%@", filePath);
//        UIImage *imageload1 = [UIImage imageWithData:[newManagedObject valueForKey:@"imagesone"]];
        [_button1 setImage:imageLoaded1 forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    }
    else {
        button1ImageName = @"addnew";
    }
}
```

Why is my image not loading?
Many thanks

Comment: Did you confirm that the file path is correct while loading the image from Documents directory?

Comment: And why you call `[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];` two times?

Comment: @Manesh  Please use this [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];  line for once in method at the end. Make it use this edited code and let me know.

Comment: @AdeelUrRehman Ive removed the duplicate dismissViewController, have kept only the last one. 
Program still fails to load image.

Comment: @SandeepAhuja Tried and didn't make a difference

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Image was saving and loading alright all along - issue turned out to be with the buttons setImage function

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
-(void)customButton1{
    if (customphoto1 == 1) {
        NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
        NSString *documentsPath = [paths objectAtIndex:0]; //Get the docs directory
        NSString *filePath = [documentsPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Button1image.png"]; 
        UIImage *imageLoaded1 = [UIImage imagewithcontentsoffile:filePath];
        NSLog(@"%@", filePath);

        [_button1 setImage:imageLoaded1 forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    }
    else {
        button1ImageName = @"addnew";
    }
}
```

**Debug:** Check whether the filepath which is getting printed is correct or not. Open this path in **Finder > CMD + Shift + G** and paste the path (remove the file name from the path, use till folder level). Then check if that particular image is available in that folder or not.

Also in your `didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo` method, you are calling `dismissViewControllerAnimated` method two times, it should be once and at the end of method.

Hope this helps

Comment: Image still returns empty I'm afraid.

Comment: Sorry i haven't done this before, so I apologise for any stupidity. Am i putting "/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/B7A2B1CC-5F2C-4170-96E0-B42E5AAC8ACD/Documents/" in the Go To The Folder search?

Comment: The Folder can't be found

Comment: I'm using iExplorer to check the application name folder, in the Documents folder of the app, the Button1image.png is visible there. Even when the application has been closed it is still there. @mrunal